# Why is it possible to have reactive elements added at mount?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

The documentation for [Reactivity in Depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) explains why adding new root-level reactive properties to an already created instance is not possible (and how to actually add them via `this.$set()`).

In that case, **why an initially empty object can be updated (and reactive) at mount time, after the instance was intialized?** Or does the initialization part includes the mount? (though it is possible to [mount an instance manually](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-mount) after the initalization)

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    myobject: {}
  },
  mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.myobject = {
        "x": 1
      }
    }, 2000)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.11/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  {{myobject}}
</div>
```

Direct further modifications after the mount are not taken into account, in line with the documentation (`this.myobject.y = 2` for instance would not work, while `this.$set(this.myobject, "y", 2)` will be fine)

Answer (score 1):

The code in your sample does not fall into the change detection caveat because you are not adding a property to `myobject` you are setting `myobject` to an *entirely new object*. Vue has no problem detecting object reference changes.

What Vue cannot detect is adding a property to an object that did not already exist. For example if you did this:

```
mounted() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.myobject.someNewProperty = "some value"
  }, 2000)
}
```

Vue would not detect the change. Here is your example updated to demonstrate that the DOM never changes after the object is changed.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    myobject: {}
  },
  mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.myobject.someNewProperty = "some value"
    }, 2000)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.11/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  {{myobject}}
</div>
```

What the documentation means when it says

> Vue does not allow dynamically adding new root-level reactive
>   properties to an already created instance.

Is that you cannot add another property to the data object after the Vue instance is created. For example this code:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    myobject: {}
  },
  mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.$set(vm.$data, 'newRootLevelProperty', "some value") 
    }, 2000)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.11/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  {{myobject}}
</div>
```

Results in the warning

> [Vue warn]: Avoid adding reactive properties to a Vue instance or its
>   root $data at runtime - declare it upfront in the data option.

But you *can* add properties to nested objects (such as `myobject`) **as long as you use $set**.